# Git setup for configuration files

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, config

I have a repository working on git. There is a file called config.php inside a directory called site_configuration. What i want is that when someone clones the repository it should download the default configuration file, and then if someone changes and pushes the new code, it should be ignored and shouldn't be pushed to the server.

**Currently in my gitignore i have this, but for some reason it still tracks the file and pushes it to the repository.**

```
site_configuration/config.php
```

Comment: So you need to create a config.php.sample and put just configuration sample in that and put the config.php in .ignore so your real credential won't upload on git and also don't give direct access to push the same repo instead use fork and pull request and then merge

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this with a normal push instead of forking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force Git to ignore changes to a tracked file (as, in your case, the site_configuration/config.php file) in a safe way. If you want the file to be ignored, you need:

1. Keep the .gitignore file as you have defined
2. Rename the site_configuration/config.php file to site_configuration/config.php_sample

Tell everybody to copy config.php_sample to config.php. Maybe you could have some automation for that.

Comment: Thanks, i have now started to follow a similar solution